# Get the first element of each element of a two-dimensional wrappedarray in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I get one dataframe by https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALSModel `recommendForUserSubset` method,

```
val recsysResult = model.recommendForAllUsers(5)
recsysResult.show(2,false)

+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|user_id|recommendations                                                                           |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1      |[[111, 0.9899166], [110, 0.9899166], [101, 0.9899166], [100, 0.9899166], [102, 0.9899166]]|
|0      |[[0, 0.9899168], [10, 0.9899168], [30, 0.9899168], [40, 0.9899168], [50, 0.9899168]]      |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now I want to get a new dataframe like

```
1 | 111 | 110 | 101 | 100 | 102  
0 | 0   | 10  | 30  | 40  | 50
```

which get the first element of each element of a two-dimensional wrappedarray `recommendations`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The structure you have is not a nested array. It is an array of structs so to extract data from it, without using udf, we would have to know the names.

Since you omitted schema, we have to rename object first:

```
val n: Int = 5
val recsysResult = model.recommendForAllUsers(n)

val  recsysResultIds = recsysResult.withColumn(
  "ids",
  col("recommendations").cast("array<struct<id:int,rating:float>>")("id")
)
```

and then select

```
recsysResultIds.select($"user_id" +: (0 to n).map(col("ids")(_)): _* )
```